# Kafka consumer is getting empty state

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka consumer application developed in .net core and created a new source connector for mongodb . The application consume almost 50k+ job , but suddenly it's going to empty state in consumer group in topic level. There is no error log. But producer side is working fine and topic is getting update always

any fix? or root cause?

Comment: Are you using Confluent Kafka .NET? Do you have multiple running instances of your application or just one? An empty consumer group can mean the application has crashed/gone into a 'dead' mode, outside of the 'polling' loop, can you check?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.